# How to call Method from Xamarin XAML Code in Button (MVVM)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Aloha,

i want to call a method (written in Model) on Button Click but without Events. 
We're working with MVVM and i want to bind the method on the specific button. 
Already tested it on that way:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="Next" Grid.RowSpan="3" BackgroundColor="Red" Command="EntryOkNext" />
```

It doesn't do anything. Something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `EntryOkNext` is a command in the ViewModel, you just need to bind the command using the correct syntax: `Command="{Binding EntryOkNext}"`.

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="3" 
        Text="Next" 
        Grid.RowSpan="3" 
        BackgroundColor="Red" 
        Command="{Binding EntryOkNext}" />
```

There are many ways you can define commands in your ViewModel.  One option could be:

```
public ICommand EntryOkNext
{
    get 
    { 
        return new Command (() => 
        {
            // your code here
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Also assuming setting BindingContext and INotifyPropertyChanged methods correctly.

Comment: Didn't noticed, that i need to have a ICommand object. Wrote an ICommand object now, bounded the Button to it and it's working. thanks! :)

Comment: @VahidShir `NotifyPropertyChanged` is not used in commands for 99/100 cases.